# Date Conversion

Tags: perl, date

In perl, how do I convert date like

```
Thu Mar 06 02:59:39 +0000 2008
```

to

```
2008-03-06T02:59:39Z
```

Tried HTTP::Date, it works if the question did not have +0000 in the string :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.5000/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm) will do this conversion.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $date = 'Thu Mar 06 02:59:39 +0000 2008 ';

my( @strp ) = (
    DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => "%a %b %d %T %z %Y", ),
    DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => "%FY%T%Z", )
);

my $dt = $strp[0]->parse_datetime( $date );

print $strp[1]->format_datetime( $dt );
```

prints 2008-03-06T02:59:39UTC

Chris

Comment: You could also use Time::Piece since it is in the CORE perl distro since V 5.10.

Answer (score 1):

So, edit it with a regex and use `HTTP::Date`:

```
( my $new_date_string = $old_state_string ) =~ s/[+-]\d{4,}\s+//;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely, positively sure that the date will ALWAYS be in that format, you can simply use regular expressions to reformat it. The only thing is that you have to have a way of converting the month to a number. That way, you don't have to download any extra modules to do the date conversion:

```
my $date = "Thu Mar 06 02:59:39 +0000 2008";  #Original String

#Create the Month Hash (you might want all twelve months).
my %monthHash (Jan => "01", Feb => 2, Mar => 3);

# Use RegEx Matching to parse your date. 
# \S+ means one or more non-spaces
# \s+ means one or more spaces
# Parentheses save that part of the string in $1, $2, $3, etc.
$date =~ m/\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s(.*)/;

my $monthString = $1;
my $day = $2;
my $time = $3;
my $year = $4;

# Convert Month string to a number.
my $month = $monthHash{$monthString};

#Reformat the string
$fmtDate="$year-$month-$day" . "T" . "$time" . "Z";
```

Otherwise I was going to say you can also try DateTime::Format::Strptime, but [Chris Charley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35812/chris-charley) beat me to it.